# Global variable and local variable clarification

Tags: c#, winforms

can you please explain me this.

```
class Program
{
    string opp;
    private void method()
    {
        string u;
        Console.WriteLine(opp + u); // i didn't initialize both local and global variables
                                    // but why local variable showing compile error as
                                    // use of unassigned local variable 'u'                                        
    }
}
```

when I debug, global variable shows 'NULL'. So is that like
Global--> default is Null for string and 0 for value types??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I debug, global variable shows 'NULL'.

Yes that should be cause you haven't initialized it and by virtue of the fact that `string` is a reference type by default it will get initialized to `NULL` wherein value types will get initialized to 0 (`false` for Boolean).

Again, key point is your `string u;` is not a class member; rather it's local variable scoped to the method `method` and so it should be initialized before you use it either by means of initializing it explicitly or passing a argument to the method and initialize it.

Answer (score 2):

In C# when you use `new Class()` expression new operator guarantees that every class field will have default value after instantination. In case of reference types this will be `null`, in case of numeric types `0` or `0.0`, in case of `bool`s this will be `false`. You can use `default(Type)` operator e.g. `default(int)` to get that default value.

In case of static fields the same rule holds, static fields gets their default value when Assembly with that class is loaded and JIT compiled (actually it is a lot more complicated - [see](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx)).

C# compiler could do this for local variables too but for efficiency reasons it leaves initialization of variables to programmer. Consider

```
int i = 3;
```

it is better to have one assigment to variable `i` than to have:

```
int i = 0; // generated by compiler
i = 3;
```

Lets dig a bit deeper into this topic, you can use [tryrosly](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) to see Intermediate Language (IL or CIL for short) generated by C# compiler (choose IL in dropdown at top of second panel). For simple method C# compiler generates:

```
public void M() {
      int i = 3;
}
```

IL:

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 4 (0x4)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.3
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

Here you have `.locals` directive that declares variables used by code. For `.locals` directive you can add `init` modifier that tells JIT compiler to set all local variables to their default values. So actually under cover .NET zeroes local variables too, it just C# language that forces you to initialize local variables implicitly.

But as noted [here](http://blog.liranchen.com/2010/07/behind-locals-init-flag.html) this zeroing of locals is optimized away if you explicitly set your local variables by JIT.

To sum up: C# language designers decided that class fields will be initialized to thier default values, while local variables will require explicit initialization before their first usage.

Comment: thanks for this brief description..learnt a bit extra as well

Answer (score 1):

Your question about variables default values.
Unassigned variable will be assigned by default value of variable's type
This is from specification of C#

> For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the
> value computed by the value-type's default constructor (Section
> 4.1.1).
>
> For a variable of a reference-type, the default value is null.

[C# language specification 5.2 Default values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171(v=vs.71).aspx)

And there is small explanation of why reference types are `null`

> Initialization to default values is typically done by having the
> memory manager or garbage collector initialize memory to all-bits-zero
> before it is allocated for use. **For this reason, it is convenient to
> use all-bits-zero to represent the null reference**.